# Java EE, creating entity object with one to one association

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, persistence

I have two entitys, A and B. A has a one to one relationship of B.

```
    class A {
        String aValue;
        B b;
    }
    class B {
       String bValue;
    }
```

The class B stuff are already pre populated. Now, a user on a website selects what B he wants to submit. On the server we get an Id of what B that was.

**The Question:**
How do I create a new A, without actually do a DB query asking for the B that has this id. I mean, the A table in database only has a id reference. One should be able to set that Id without fetching the B.

Comment: If by Persistence you're referring to JPA, wouldn't OneToOne be what you need ( http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne )

Comment: But wouldn't that require me to look up B first ?

I have the id of B, and I know it is already in database. 

As of now, I would do: 

A a = new A();
a.setAValue("aaa")
B b = em.find(idOFB); // Here I am performing what I see as an unessessary db query. I should be able to set b in A without fetching the Object.
a.setB(b);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JPA and Assuming the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
class A {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
    String aValue;
    @OneToOne
    B b;
    // Getters, setters and other stuff
}

@Entity
@Table(name="B")
class B {
   @Id
   @Column(name="id")
   private int id;
   Integer Id;
   String bValue;
   // Getters, setters and other stuff
}
```

If you now the id of entity B. You can simply make persist as follows:

```
B b = new B();
b.setId(1000); //Assuming that you know the id. 
               //There is no necessary fill all the object. Just the PK is needed.
A a = new A();
a.setId(100);
a.setAValue("nothing");
a.setB(b);
em.persist(a);
```

I have tested this with Hibernate as Persistence Provider. If you are using other ORM please specify it.

Comment: Ok, that is what I was interested in! 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at JPA 2.0.

With JPA you can define a relationship between 2 entites to automatically retrieve the related entities.